# Getting large Facebook profile picture with url

Tags: ios, facebook, url

So I'm trying to get the large Facebook profile image using a url. When using this url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/10153207714499645/picture?access_token=<access token>
```

I get a 50x50 image. However, when I add the variable `?type=large`, I get

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) type must be one of the following values: small, normal, album, large, square",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

my url looks like this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/10153207714499645/picture?type=large?access_token=<access token>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `&` rather than `?` between parameters.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/10153207714499645/picture?type=large&access_token=<access token>
```